Qt/QML issue: when launching cannot find main.qml file
My C++/QML app compiles, but at launch I get this error:
00:51:26: Starting /home/pietro/QtQuickTest/build/Desktop_latest-Debug/appQtQuickTest...
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/qt/qml/main.qml: No such file or directory

The /qt/qml/main.qml path should be correct, since I am using Qt 6.6.
The original main.qml file is in the project root directory ., and a copy is made during the build in ./build/Desktop_latest-Debug/appQtQuickTest/.
In the main.cpp file there is the line:
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qt/qml/main.qml")));

I also tried with the old style approach, resulting in the same error:
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

I checked all over the project, and there are no upper/lowercase issues.
This is the CMakeLists.txt file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(QtQuickTest VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.6 COMPONENTS Quick Gui REQUIRED)

qt_standard_project_setup(REQUIRES 6.6)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

qt_add_executable(appQtQuickTest
    main.cpp
    TreeItem.h
    TreeItem.cpp
    TreeModel.h
    TreeModel.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(appQtQuickTest
    URI QtQuickTest
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES
        main.qml
    RESOURCES
        Description.md
        test.json
)

target_link_libraries(appQtQuickTest
    PRIVATE Qt6::Gui Qt6::Quick
)

The following QRC file is produced by the build system: QtQuickTest/build/Desktop_latest-Debug/.rcc/appQtQuickTest_raw_qml_0.qrc:
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/qt/qml/QtQuickTest/">
    <file alias="main.qml">/home/pietro/QtQuickTest/main.qml</file>
    <file alias="test.json">/home/pietro/QtQuickTest/test.json</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>

What am I doing wrong?

maybe: engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qt/qml/QtQuickTest/main.qml")));

@eyllanesc - Yes, specifying the project name in the path it works. But is it a correct way to do it? I have never seen it before...

Note: You are not creating the qrc explicitly, but the cmake configuration produces the .qrc and you have set the following as the uri: URI QtQuickTest, the result being the path of the file.

OK, now I got it. If you write it as an answer I will accept it. Thank you.

The error message (qrc:/qt/qml/main.qml: No such file or directory) indicates that the application can't find the file within the resource path (qrc:/).
Make sure main.qml is included in resources.qrc:
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource prefix="/qt/qml">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>

update:
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/qt/qml">
    <file alias="main.qml">qml/main.qml</file>
    <file alias="test.json">resources/test.json</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>


I added that QRC file, but I still get the same error. Is it correct to place it in the project source root directory?

The recommended path is QtQuickTest/qml/main.qml.

Does your second QRC file substitute the first one?

@Pietro, yes, it does. Use it together with engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qt/qml/main.qml")));.

I get the same error. So far, the only way to fix it has been @eyllanesc
